# Unable to get response for utterance in RASA chatbot

Tags: python, data-science, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa

I am unable to get any response related to the subject for my utterance in RASA chatbot framework.

When i enter :

"What is corona status"
Bot is  sending only below response.
Sorry, I didn't get that, can you rephrase your question?

For other utterances it is working fine.

## Below is the content of nlu.md file

### intent:ask_coronastatus

- what is corona status
- what is status of corna
- what is the status of corona here
- provide current status of corona
- what is [total corona cases] (corona_number) of corona in [india] (corona_country)
- how many [corona] (corona_number)are there in country

## Below is the content of stories.md file:

### interactive_story_29

- greet

  - utter_greet
- ask_coronastatus

  - corona_status_form
  - form{"name": "corona_status_form"}
  - slot{"corona_number":"corona","corona_number":"null"}
  - form{"name": null}
  - utter_coronafeedback
- coronaaffirm

  - utter_coronaaffirm_response
- thank_you

  - utter_bye

### interactive_story_30

- greet

  - utter_greet
- ask_coronastatus

  - corona_status_form
  - form{"name": "corona_status_form"}
  - slot{"corona_number":"corona","corona_number":"null"}
  - form{"name": null}
- thank_you

  - utter_bye

### interactive_story_31

- greet

  - utter_greet
- ask_coronastatus

  - corona_status_form
  - form{"name": "corona_status_form"}
  - slot{"corona_number":"corona","corona_number":"null"}
  - form{"name": null}
  - utter_coronafeedback

## Below is the content of domain.yml file:

````
- utter_coronaaffirm_response
- utter_ask_corona_number

intents:
- ask_coronastatus

entities:
- corona_number
- corona_country

responses:
  utter_coronaaffirm_response:
  - text: "Great ,you got the corona status now!"
  utter_coronafeedback:
  - text: "Was i able to provide Corona status?"


slots:
  corona_country:
    type: text
  corona_number:
    type: unfeaturized  

forms:
  - corona_status_form```
````

Comment: Could you add your stories file as well? Also it will help if you render the text in code cells with markdown. You can use three ticks (```) before and after a code block to make it render nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Few errors were reported related to slots mismtach from action file. I corrected them and restarted server . nul.md ,stories.md and domain.yml file content is correct.

It works now.